# Codeigniter, Bootstrap, drop-down list, one value saved instead of all, to a database

Tags: php, ajax, codeigniter

I’d like to thank everyone in advance.

I’m using this code in codeigniter,

I need someone’s help creating the php code for the drop-down list that’s part of a modal.

I have the easy part done, need assistance with the hard part.

```
[![Drop-down list][1]][1]
```

The example above, I’d like to save all the values to the database.

Right now with this code,all it saves is one value, not all.

What would be the best way to accomplish this with the code below.

This is what I have so far, saves one value only,thanks.

```
    <label class="control-label col-md-3">LS</label>
    <div class="col-md-9">     
    <select name="LS" class="selectpicker" multiple size = 2>
    <option value='LRG'>LRG</option>
    <option value='SML'>SML</option>
    </select>
```

I added the view to show what I have so far.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <tr>
    <th>First Name</th>
    <th>LS</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    </tbody>
    </table>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    var table;
    $(document).ready(function() {
    table = $('#table').DataTable({ 
    "lengthMenu": [[25, 50, -1], [25, 50, "All"]],    
    "processing": true,
    "serverSide": true,
    "order": [],
    "ajax": {
    "url": "<?php echo site_url('runner/ajax_list')?>",
    "type": "POST",
    "data": function ( data ) {
     data.FirstName = $('#FirstName').val();
    data.LS = $('#LS').val();
    }
    },
    "columnDefs": [
    { 
    "targets": [ 0 ],
    "orderable": false
     }
    ]
    });
    $('#btn-filter').click(function(){
    table.ajax.reload();
    });
    $('#btn-reset').click(function(){ 
    $('#form-filter')[0].reset();
    table.ajax.reload();
    });
    });
    </script>
    <div class = "row">
    <div class="modal fade" id="modal_form" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-header">
    <button type="button" class="close" aria-label="Close"><span aria- 
    hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
    <h3 class="modal-title">Person Form</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body form">
    <form action="#" id="form" class="form-horizontal">  
    <input type="hidden" value="" name="id"/> 
    <div class="form-body">
    <div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label col-md-3">FirstName</label>
    <div class="col-md-9">
    <input name="FirstName" placeholder="First Name" class="form-control" 
    type="text">
    <span class="help-block"></span>
    </div>
    </div> 
    <div class="form-body">
    <div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label col-md-3">LS</label>
    <div class="col-md-9">     
    <select name="LS" class="selectpicker" multiple size = 2>
    <option value='LRG'>LRG</option>
    <option value='SML'>SML</option>
    </select>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div> 
    </div>
    </form>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer" style="padding:2px 2px;">
    <button type="button" id="btnSave" onclick="save()" class="btn btn- 
    primary">Save</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data- 
    dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    var save_method;
    var table;
    var arr = $(this).val();
    $(document).ready(function() {
    $("input").change(function(){
    $(this).parent().parent().removeClass('has-error');
    $(this).next().empty();
    });
    $("textarea").change(function(){
    $(this).parent().parent().removeClass('has-error');
    $(this).next().empty();
    });
    $("select").change(function(){
    $(this).parent().parent().removeClass('has-error');
    $(this).next().empty();
    });
    });
    function add_person()
    {
    save_method = 'add';
    $('#form')[0].reset();
    $.fn.modal.prototype.constructor.Constructor.DEFAULTS.backdrop = 'static';
    $.fn.modal.prototype.constructor.Constructor.DEFAULTS.keyboard =  false;
    $('.form-group').removeClass('has-error');
    $('.help-block').empty();
    $('#modal_form').modal('show');
    $('.modal-title').text('Add New Resident'); 
    }
    function reload_table()
    {
    table.ajax.reload(null,true); //reload datatable ajax 
    }
    function save()
    {
    $('#btnSave').text('saving...');
    $('#btnSave').attr('disabled',true);
    var url;
    if(save_method === 'add') 
    {
    url = "<?php echo site_url('runner/ajax_add')?>";
    }
    else
    {
    url = "<?php echo site_url('runner/ajax_update')?>";
    }
    $.ajax({
    url : url,
    type: "POST",
    data: $('#form').serialize(),
    dataType: "JSON",
    success: function(data)
    {
    if(data.status)
    {
    $('#modal_form').modal('hide');
    reload_table();
    }
    else
    {
    for (var i = 0; i < data.inputerror.length; i++) 
    {
    $('[name="'+data.inputerror[i]+'"]').parent().parent().addClass('has- 
    error'); 
    $('[name="'+data.inputerror[i]+'"]').next().text(data.error_string[i]);
    }
    }
    $('#btnSave').text('save');
    $('#btnSave').attr('disabled',false);
    },
    error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown)
    {

    alert('Error adding / update data!!!!');
    $('#btnSave').text('save'); 
    $('#btnSave').attr('disabled',false);
    }
    });
    }
    </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

The Controller

```
    <?php
    defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

    class Runner extends CI_Controller {
    public function __construct()
    {
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->model('runner_model','runner');
    }
    public function index()
    {
    $this->load->helper('url');
    $this->load->helper('form');
    $persons = $this->runner->get_list_countries();
    $opt = array('' => 'All person');
    foreach ($persons as $person) {
    $opt[$person] = $person;
    }       
    $this->load->view('runner_view', $person);
    }
    public function ajax_list()
    {
    $list = $this->runner->get_datatables();
    $data = array();
    $no = $_POST['start'];
    foreach ($list as $residents) {
    $no++;
    $row = array();
    $row[] = $residents->FirstName;
    $row[] = $residents->LS;
    $data[] = $row;
    }
    $output = array(
    "draw" => $_POST['draw'],
    "recordsTotal" => $this->runner->count_all(),
    "recordsFiltered" => $this->runner->count_filtered(),
    "data" => $data,
    );
    //output to json format
    echo json_encode($output);
    }
    public function ajax_add()
    {
    $data = array(
    'FirstName' => $this->input->post('FirstName'),
    'LS' => $this->input->post('LS'),
    );
    $insert=$this->runner->save($data);
    echo json_encode(array("status" => TRUE));
    }
    }
```

The Model.

```
    class Runner_model extends CI_Model {

    var $table = 'keeprunner';
    var $column_order = array(null, 'FirstName','LS'); //set column field 
    database for datatable orderable
    var $column_search = array('FirstName','LS'); //set column field database 
    for datatable searchable 
    var $order = array('id' => 'DESC'); // default order 

    public function __construct()
    {
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->database();
    }
    private function _get_datatables_query()
    {
    if($this->input->post('FirstName'))
    {
    $this->db->like('FirstName', $this->input->post('FirstName'));
    }

    if($this->input->post('LS'))
    {
    $this->db->like('LS', $this->input->post('LS'));
    }
    $this->db->from($this->table);
    }

    public function get_datatables()
    {
    $this->_get_datatables_query();
    if($_POST['length'] != -1)
    $this->db->limit($_POST['length'], $_POST['start']);
    $query = $this->db->get();
    return $query->result();
    }

    public function count_filtered()
    {
    $this->_get_datatables_query();
    $query = $this->db->get();
    return $query->num_rows();
    }

    public function count_all()
    {
    $this->db->from($this->table);
    return $this->db->count_all_results();
    }

    public function get_list_countries()
    {
    $this->db->select('FirstName');
    $this->db->from($this->table);
    $this->db->order_by('FirstName','asc');
    $query = $this->db->get();
    $result = $query->result();
    $persons = array();
    foreach ($result as $row) 
    {
    $persons[] = $row->FirstName;
    }
    return $persons;
    }
    public function get_by_id($id)
    {
    $this->db->from($this->table);
    $this->db->where('id',$id);
    $query = $this->db->get();
    return $query->row();
    }    
    public function save($data)
    {
    $this->db->insert($this->table, $data);
    return $this->db->insert_id();
    }   
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, use name with `[]` for multiple selects like this: `<select name="LS[]" class="selectpicker" multiple size="2">`. Because this select sends multiple values to server.
Second, I don't know table `keeprunner` structure, but you must think over how to store multiple values to db:

- separate row for each LS value. It needs to use several inserts;
- one row, but LS value is storing in serialised view, i.e. `['LRG', 'SML']`. For this you need some preprocessing before insert like this: `'LS' => json_encode($this->input->post('LS')),`.

Comment: Can you or anyone, show me an example of how to do this pre-processing?
Table  : ID int(11) Null=no, Auto_Increment, (2) FirstName varchar(50) Null(No) (3) LS varchar(10) Null(No)

Comment: You can use `'LS' => json_encode($this->input->post('LS')),` instead `'LS' => $this->input->post('LS'),`.

Comment: Changing to 'LS' => json_encode($this->input->post('LS')) and select name="LS[], fixed the “saving 1 value only problem”. Saving in the database is still not correct, looks like this ["LRG","SM instead of LRG SML. Anyway to fix that? Thanks.

Comment: There aren't such conditions in question. For 'LRG SML' you need to use `implode(' ', $this->input->post('LS'))`

Comment: After changing the LS in “public function ajax_update”, to this “implode(' ', $this->input->post('LS')),”
The update modal, populates every field except for the LS one. 
Might this be the culprit-- $('[name="LS"]').val(data.LS);

Comment: Yes, you need to convert string with spaces to array like this: `$('[name="LS"]').val(data.LS.split(' '));`

Comment: Still having an issue with updating the modal, populates all fields with the right value, except the LS field, LS shows “nothing selected”.